# How can i pass the value from the current page & display those values in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On click of link from current page I want to open, new URL in new tab/POPUP. How can i pass the values (bulk of values) from the current page and display those values in new tab? 
 I don't want to use URL Vars.
I tried using 
`Cachehandler.getInstance().setValues()` to set them in current page,and tried getting it using `Cachehandler.getInstance().getValues()` in a new tab, but at this time it is getting as undefined.

Comment: Are the pages on the same domain? If that is the case, you can use cookies or localstorage.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: yes, pages are of same domain .

Comment: What's `Cachehandler`?

Comment: they are just like setters and getters . using to save some values and  pass them from one page to another page.these are not working when trying to open url in new tab .

Comment: Were is `Cachehandler` from?, it's not in `jquery`, `javascript` or `html`, are you using some framework like `Joomla`?.  If so you will get a much better response if you have the correct tags.  A generic way client side is like Rohit has said `cookie`'s or `localStorage`.

Answer (score 0):

Use **HTML Web Storage**

With web storage, web applications can **store data locally within the user's browser**. Web storage is more secure, and large amounts of data can be stored locally, **without affecting website performance**.

Unlike cookies, the storage limit is far larger (at least 5MB) and information is never transferred to the server.

Web storage is per origin (per domain and protocol). All pages, from one origin, can store and access the same data.

**Example**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

 <div id="result"></div>

<script>

if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") 
{
 localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");

 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
}
 else
 {
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}
```

For More Info Take look at here : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp